# Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.8.0

Tags: android, maven, gradle, sdk, accessibility

Got the notification email 29sep22 that `com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.8.0` was available but have not been able to download via gradle in my app sync.

Get the following error result: `"Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.8.0."`

I can access `com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.7.0` with no problems.

Any idea what is the reason

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
  implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.8.0"
}
```

This is what given in their documentation. looks correct as per your question.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I have. Just not working.

Comment: Tried again this morning, still not resolving for   implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.8.0"

Comment: Check this link.  https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/3780

Comment: thanks, took a look at that and it did not resolve my issue